# Extrude Region offset on meshes reaching impractical values

Tags: transforms, extrude

I have a .blend file that I transferred from my office laptop to my personal PC. I have only started tinkering with Blender so I should have downloaded the same version of Blender altogether (3.3.0).

[image: I am currently modelling a small mesh for a 3D print.]

The issue is that on my personal PC, the 'Extrude Faces Along Normal' function jumps to an offset much larger than the size of the mesh itself.

[image: Offset/thickness over tenfold of any direction in the XY plane.]

How should I fix it so I can measure against a proper offset like below?
[image]

Comment: Not sure of the reason, but your first image shows that the object's scale is set to a very small value (0.006) so I'd apply that via Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode first and then try extruding your cylinder in case that's affecting things.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to this Scale? Mildly confused as to how I had not the need to do this on my other workstation.

Comment: As I said, Ctrl-A > Scale is the shortcut. No idea why you didn't need to do it on your other machine, but it's always something you should check, especially for things like bevelling, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eason, doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale* and normalizing the XYZ scale to $1.0$ is the solution to the issue.